Tabler icons for React slowing down app on initial load
Given a new React app using Vite with no content yet ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-7xucud?file=src%2Fmain.tsx )
When I'm using Tabler Icons for React ( https://tabler.io/docs/icons/react ) and change the content of main.tsx to this ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-sszcqw?file=src%2Fmain.tsx )
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { IconArrowLeft } from '@tabler/icons-react';

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <div>
      <div>See icon below</div>
      <IconArrowLeft />
    </div>
  </StrictMode>
);

I get huge performance issues. The initial load time is increased and whenever I'm refreshing the page it takes a lot of time. Did I miss something in the docs I should setup before using the icons?
I see a lot of network requests for tabler, it seems the library is fetching some chunks first.

You can try import 'import  IconArrowLeft from '@tabler/icons-react/IconArrowLeft';

That didn't work, the file doesn't exist. Also tried iconArrowLeft, icon-arrow-left and icon_arrow_left

same issue? https://github.com/tabler/tabler-icons/issues/1233

yeah, this seems to be the issue!
